# " Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M1:test (default-test)" while running Maven from command line

Tags: java, maven

When I do in command line:

```
mvn clean test -Ptest -Dbrowser=chrome -Dtest=TestRunner
```

then I receive error as in title of this question. When I run TestRunner directly from IDE then everything runs smoothly. It also runs when I use failsafe instead of surefire (with same configuration).

Surefire configuration:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
                <shutdown>exit</shutdown>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <browser>${browser}</browser>
                    <browser.version>${browser.version}</browser.version>
                    <proxy.user-password>${proxy.user-password}</proxy.user-password>
                    <grid.use>${grid.use}</grid.use>
                    <grid.hub.address>${grid.hub.address}</grid.hub.address>
                    <profileId>${project.activeProfiles[0].id}</profileId>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
                <forkCount>5</forkCount>
                <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>listener</name>
                        <value>com.adaptavist.tm4j.junit.ExecutionListener</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Stacktrace:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M1:test (default-test) on project x: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M1:test (default-test) on project att-portals: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:830)
```

Comment: You should add the whole error output cause there is more on the console...furthermore please show your pom file...

Comment: @khmarbaise: I've updated question with Surefire configuration and stack trace.

Comment: Could you please try to set `<failIfNoTests>false</failIfNoTests>`?

Answer (score -1):

You can add a verify to your test method, for example:

```
try {
  logCount = this.service.execute(les);
} catch (final Exception e) {
  fail();
}
assertEquals(1, logCount);
verify(ops, times(2)).ingest(anyString(), anyList());
```